# Showing that $(Y, \| \cdot \|)$ is Banach, iff $Y \subset (X,\| \cdot \|)$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Let $Y$ be a subspace of the Banach space $(X, \| \cdot \|)$. Show that $(Y, \| \cdot \|)$ is Banach **iff** $Y$ is closed.

**Question :** Any tips or hints on how to start this ? I see myself to be lost, mostly due to me struggling with real analysis definitions, such as a topological space being closed. Even then, though, what would be a proper way to start or elaborate the proof asked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Suppose $Y$ is closed.  Let $y_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$; show that it converges to a member of $Y$.
2. Suppose $Y$ is not closed.  Find a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ that does not converge to a member of $Y$.

Comment: For (1) : Suppose $Y$ is closed. Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Let $\epsilon >0$. Then $\exists k_0 \in \mathbb N : \| y_k - y_l \| < \epsilon / 2 \; \forall k,l \geq k_0$. Every term $x_k$ is of the form $y_k = (y_n^k)_{n \in \mathbb N} = (y_1^k, y_2^k, \dots)$. Now, $\forall n : | y_n^k - y_n^l | \leq \| y_n^k - y_n^l \| < \epsilon /2 \; \forall k, l \geq k_0$ which means that $(y_n^k)$ is Cauchy $\forall n$. Thus it converges to some real number $y_n$, which means $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_n^k = x_n \forall n$.

Comment: Continuing (1) : Let $ x = (x_n) = (x_1, x_2, \dots)$. Taking $l \to \infty$ we yield $$\| y_n^k - y_n \| \leq \epsilon /2$$ Now for $n \to \infty$ we have : $$\| y_k - y \| \leq \epsilon /2 < \epsilon $$ thus the sequence converges to some $y$.

Comment: Is this correct this far ? How would I show now that $y \in Y$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the fact that a subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed.

Comment: Well, that's pretty straight forward **if** this fact is taken as known, but I think that the exercise wants us to work around proving this fact, thus since $Y \subset X$ which is Banach and thus complete, it should be complete to be Banach and thus closed from the fact proven. But how to prove this fact ?

Comment: I could provide an answer, but then I would simply be repeating the answer provided by Robert Israel. On the other hand, it **is** a very well-known fact.

Comment: We haven't been taught of it as a fact yet, still in the very beginnings. I think Robert's answer is really how I need to learn to think regarding proofs over functional analysis!